# Default way for index of files of external drive (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, search-indexing

Is there a standard way to save an index of files that sit on an external drive in Windows 10?

The intention is not to do fast searches for files on that drive, but rather to have a list at any given time of all files that were on that drive, for the case of it getting lost, breaking etc.

The data is not important enough to back it up, but if the drive should get inaccessible from any cause, I would like to know which files I lost.

It's btw clear to me, that one could write a script that auto-executes on drive connect and catch events for file transfers on that drive etc., but I hope that there is a standard way or a neat third party tool to achieve this easily and automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's likely a more elegant solution than the following, but one option is using `Dir` or `Ls`

- PowerShell: `Dir`

  ```powershell
  Cmd /C Dir /S "D:" > "D:\index.txt"
  ```
- PowerShell: `Ls`

  ```powershell
  Ls -Recurse "D:" > "D:\index.txt"
  ```

Another option could be using `Rsync`, which can create a log of all files that's updated when ran *(there should be a way to pipe that so you're not actually copying files)*, however, [`Cygwin`](https://www.cygwin.com/) would be required to install.

Comment: Thats actually quite close to what I've been looking for. I'll just put this as a script in the task scheduler, overwriting old logs after a couple of days and should something bad happen to the drive I can have a fast look at the files that were on it, perfect!